# Unity 5.3.5 3D/XCode8 Google cardboard build error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, xcodebuild, google-cardboard

Hi guys I'm having issues building my google cardboard project within xcode8, whenever i build the project this is te following error which i seem to be getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_endSettingsDialog", referenced from:
>         -[DismissDialogViewController viewDidAppear:] in libvrunity.a(unity.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've been looking around on the forums and seeing people suggesting copying the google cardbord sdk into your project but these are c# for unity so i'm not too sure as to how this would work....

Comment: getting crazy to find a solution to the same problem. I cannot build my Unity game in XCode